# How to setup GPU (AMD Radeon R5 M330) for Tensorflow in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, amd-gpu

I'm new to TensorFlow, trying to install TensorFlow on my Windows laptop and configure the built-in AMD Radeon R5 M330, any guide/steps would be really helpful.

I've installed the following so far

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
pip install tf-nightly-gpu
```

I'm getting the following warning when I import TensorFlow

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
2021-07-27 14:11:41.339706: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-07-27 14:11:41.339901: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

"TensorFlow GPU support requires an assortment of drivers and libraries. To simplify installation and avoid library conflicts, we recommend using a TensorFlow Docker image with GPU support (Linux only). This setup only requires the NVIDIA® GPU drivers."

-- You won't be able to do this with simple `pip`. You need Nvidia GPU drivers, CUDO toolkit, CUPTI and cuDNN SDK